# XPATH в зависимости от содержания контейнера

Tags: регулярные-выражения, dom, xpath

1

```
<div class="common">
some code
<a href="#" class="link">link</a>
some code
</div>
```

2

```
<div class="common">
some code
<a href="#" class="link">link</a>
some code
<div class="none">some txt</div>
some code
</div>
```

Вопрос.
Требуется забрать (достучаться) к `<a>` с классом `link`, но не забирать в `<div class="common">`, если в нем присутствует `<div class="none">some txt</div>`.

В примере выше, задача забрать `<a>` с первого варианта, со второго нет.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
"//div[@class='common' and not(div[@class='none'])]/a[@class='link']"
```

Собственно, расписывать особо нечего. Находим `div` с классом `common` и не содержащий `div` с классом `none`. И берём `a` с классом `link`.